# How can I repair a Whirpool washing machine that spins but doesn't agitate?

Tags: washing-machine, clothes-washer, washer

I have a Whirlpool NAV2330AWW washing machine that won't agitate. During agitation cycle the washer is extremely noisy. The first thing I fixed was a broken idler pulley (the plastic portion had broken away from the metal inner bushing). The motor runs during the agitate portion, but I don't see any movement on the upper portion of the transmission.

Could somebody help me diagnose what may be wrong? If there is some small component inside the transmission that needs to be replaced, I'm all for it. If I need a whole transmission, I doubt that it is economical to repair.

[Parts Diagram](http://www.partselect.com/Models/NAV2330AWW/Sections/TRANSMISSION-AND-BRAKE/?ModelID=142111&ModelNum=NAV2330AWW&mfgModelNum=&ManufactureID=&Selected=58183&Position=7&mfg=Maytag&Type=Washer&Mark=7)

All of the belt pulleys move. The shaft above the transmission going to the agitator doesn't move though. It all works on a spin cycle though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can buy *parts* for the transmission or if you'd even be able to repair it to working order anyway. Being that it's a $300 assembly, isn't it new washer time? If you can't find individual parts for the transmission, the point is moot. I had one with a bad main bearing; it would agitate but couldn't spin under load. I'll be the first to admit that I'm just a parts swapper; entirely disassembling a washing machine would not make me any money and would probably optionally cost you the same, in lost time (and more parts when it breaks again next year; you'd still have an old washer).

Comment: Definitely agreed that if the transmission is the problem it's not economical to replace. I see in the parts diagram that there is a brake rotor assembly and pads, etc... I don't think that my symptom indicates a brake problem, but my hope is to test a few parts and identify if some other (cheaper) part is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to a problem I recently had with my washer.  In my case, the washer would agitate, but not spin.

I [asked a question about it here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/44915/18557).  If you go there, you'll see a test that I did on my transmission which confirmed that I did have a bad transmission.  If you take your transmission off and rotate the input shaft and don't get the correct output, or if you are able to hold the output shaft still and continue to spin the input shaft, that would indicate to me that your transmission is bad.  If you've inspected all the other parts and haven't noticed anything broken, I'd say that it's probably the transmission anyway.

I was able to find a cheap transmission for my washer, but it looks like your transmission is going to cost you more than double what it cost me for mine, so it probably is not worth it to fix.